# How to create a friendly date format (for example "submitted 2 days ago")

Tags: php, date, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

I want to format dates on my social web app much like Digg.com and other sites do. There, you see very friendly dates, such as:

- just now
- 3 minutes ago
- one hour ago
- 2 weeks ago
- 6 months ago
- etc

Before I wrap my head around creating such a thing, does anyone know of any ready-to-go script for this where I simply insert a datestamp and a friendly date text is given based on how it related to the current time?

PS: I need this in PHP, but pseudo-code or any other language is fine too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time). It has a flurry of code samples on how to accomplish this, in addition to the code this very site uses. I glanced at it and there seems to be a PHP implementation posted there too.

In addition to all this, if are you using jQuery you can do this client-side with something like the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin. It has the advantage of updating the text as time passes so if you load a page and it says "posted 5 minutes ago" and look again 5 minutes later, it says "posted 10 minutes ago"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for the answers, and sorry for the duplicate question. I did not find the duplicate when I was looking for it because I did not really know what search terms to use.

Anyways, I have my problem solved thanks to the PHP translation of the code used by stackoverflow. I made one tiny change in calculating the delta:

```
$delta = strtotime(gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())) - $time;
```

Since I am storing my dates in MySQL as timestamp in the GMT format, I have to use the same for calculating the CURRENT time. This makes for a timezone neutral comparison, which is exactly what is needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in SQL:

[Best way to convert DateTime to "n Hours Ago" in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149/best-way-to-convert-datetime-to-n-hours-ago-in-sql)