# How might I format relative dates the way Stack Overflow does "member since" and "last seen"?

Tags: php, date, formatting, relative-date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

I want to know how to display these data as seen on stackoverflow.com profile page. I have the timestamp of users registered date and last visit date. But I need to display using stackoverflow.com format.

For example:

> Member since: 9 months
>   Last seen: just now

Is there any script to convert these dates and display in such format?

Comment: There are allot of ways to do this. For a specific "how-to", what language are you using?

Comment: This belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Code: why? He's not asking a question about SO, he's just using it as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670161/how-to-create-a-friendly-date-format-for-example-submitted-2-days-ago) which is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) which has some great code samples including PHP.

> In addition to all this, if are you using jQuery you can do this
>   client-side with something like the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin. It has the
>   advantage of updating the text as time passes so if you load a page
>   and it says "posted 5 minutes ago" and look again 5 minutes later, it
>   says "posted 10 minutes ago"

Comment: Good catch. But next time, consider flagging so a moderator can close with a link to that question...