# Date as relative text (e.g. Today, Yesterday, 1 Week Ago) in .NET

Tags: .net, string, date, date-format

Does anyone have a simple function at hand for converting a date to a simple date-relative string in .NET?

E.g. 14-Oct-09 would read "Today", 13-Oct-09 would read "Yesterday" and 7-Oct-09 would read "1 Week Ago" etc.

Comment: Interesting take.  I'm not certain you're going to get any answer beyond "roll your own" :)

Comment: One of the very first questions on this site dealt with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Comment: And for a way of achieving this in SQL (should you ever want to): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149/best-way-to-convert-datetime-to-n-hours-ago-in-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would indeed have to roll your own method of doing this, like *JustLoren* said.

This is an extension method I've been using. It is [GateKiller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12) script made into an extension method. So full credit to him. You could easily change it to however you want it.

```
public static string ToTimeSinceString(this DateTime value)
{
    const int SECOND = 1;
    const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - value.Ticks);
    double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;

    // Less than one minute
    if (seconds < 1 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";

    if (seconds < 60 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";

    if (seconds < 120 * MINUTE)
        return "an hour ago";

    if (seconds < 24 * HOUR)
        return ts.Hours + " hours ago";

    if (seconds < 48 * HOUR)
        return "yesterday";

    if (seconds < 30 * DAY)
        return ts.Days + " days ago";

    if (seconds < 12 * MONTH) {
        int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
        return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
    }

    int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
    return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
}
```

Comment: That seems to come straight from the accepted answer on the question I linked to in the question comments ;o)

Comment: Really sorry about that. I had forgotten where it came from. Added credit to answer.

Comment: You should probably use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` instead of `.Now` to stay in line with best practices assuming your DB is storing stuff in UTC.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this extension method?

```
public static string Stringfy(this DateTime date)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - date.Date).TotalDays == 0)
        return "Today";

    if ((DateTime.Now - date.Date).TotalDays == 1)
        return "Yesterday";

    // ...

    return "A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away...";
}
```

Comment: Isn't TotalDays a double? Maybe a Truncate is in order to get the whole days or even use DateTime.Now.Date instead of DateTime.Now